# Read an arbitrary string from the console

Tags: git, bash, console

I've a bash function that looks like this.

```
function gg() {
  git add . && git commit -v -m "$*"
}
```

It takes any arguments from the console and uses it as a commit message.

The problem is that it wont handle special characters like `()`, `´`, `"` and so on.
Is there a way to escape ingoing params so I can use any given arguments?

This is how to use the function.

> gg Fixed all bugs (closed 123)

It runs this command.

> git add . && git commit -v -m "Fixed all bugs (closed 123)"

That example will return this error.

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error isn't coming out of your script, it's coming from bash, which is trying to interpret your special characters before it even gets passed into your script.

```
gg "Fixed all bugs (closed 123)"
```

should work fine.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I dont want to use the "".

Comment: @Oleander: There's no way around it.